# Bluetooth Connection using Pybluez on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, sound, python, bluetooth, bluez

So, I recently got into Bluetooth programming and I have no previous experience with it. What I'm trying to do is to start my audio device, pair with it, then connect to it and play a bunch of test tones on it. After that, the device (Bluetooth speaker) would be disconnected and removed.

I used "sdptool -browse" and discovered that the audio sink service uses L2CAP. So I wrote a very simple python program using L2CAP to connect to the speaker. I was successful in establishing a connection and I see that device is connected. But I haven't been able to stream any audio through the speaker. Any ideas on how I can do that?

I initially used "import wave" and parsed up the audio file into frames. Then I used socket.send(frame) to send the data. This approach does not work, and in fact forces my bluetooth speaker to power off.

Please help me out